# PrimeFaces 3.0.M4 <p:cellEditor> NullPointerException

Tags: java, primefaces, nullpointerexception

Here is my page that works:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable value="#{testBean.testList}" var="test">
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{test}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Here is my page that does not work:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable value="#{testBean.testList}" var="test">
            <p:column>
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{test}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{test}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>   
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Here is the error that I receive:

```
Nov 22, 2011 10:17:05 PM org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter handleThrowable
SEVERE: An exception occurred
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at     org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIData.restoreDescendantComponentStates(UIData.java:718)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.restoreDescendantComponentStates(UIData.java:729)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.restoreDescendantComponentStates(UIData.java:729)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutPreserveComponentState(UIData.java:580)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:500)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:604)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:227)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:205)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:97)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeEnd(UIData.java:1416)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:672)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:668)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1483)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:281)
at     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
... 17 more
```

It only seems to occur when I put the cell editor in, I made the bean as minimalistic as possible.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a list member value this way:

```
<p:inputText value="#{test}" style="width:100%" />
```

You should assign the inputText value to a bean member/variable and then add it to your list... or better, `work with objects`. 
However I tried your code and I'm not getting any error (doesn't work but no error), though I'm using Mojarra and not MyFaces.

Comment: Hi Spauny, thanks for the prompt reply.  I was originally working with lists of objects that had attributes and was receiving the same error, I just simplified it down for the purpose of example.  Perhaps I will give the Mojorra implementation a go.

Comment: @jimmy You do **not** have to change the implementation because of this error: **try to deal with it**... What if this works fine with Mojarra and after awhile you get another error? You change back to MyFaces? It's absurd! Tell me what you wanna do/try, post the code and deal with the problems! Also it's important to have the latest MyFaces version compatible with your server(servlet container)!

Comment: That's a fair point.  I'm evaluating various implementations.  PrimeFaces looks like a great component suite, it's just the first component I try to use didn't actually work.  I'll have to look into it some more.  Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the Primefaces tag description - you can find there all the relevant resources. Good Luck and welcome to Primefaces world! If you have problems/misunderstandings I'm more than happy yo help you! (Also do not forget to accept an answer for every question)

Comment: Just to keep this updated ... I did get it working, whilst I'm not sure what the actual problem was it was to do with the incorrect wrapping of parent tags.  If I can recreate the scenario I'll try give a more detailed description.  Just make sure your page structure is correct.